# Facebook auth Badge

Tags: facebook

is any **oficoal** widget with button login so user click button and login any site with fb profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has a good bit of documentation for developers.  It sounds like you're looking for the [Single Sign-on](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web#login) functionality.  More information about Facebook authentication [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).